# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at Object.ApiClientService.sendRequest

Tags: angular

Below is my saveComponent code. All my requests are  not working fine. When I do the post request, I am getting "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

[image: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at Object.ApiClientService.sendRequest]

**SaveComponent.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Liv} from '../../services/models/liv.model';
import {Livre} from '../../services/models/livre.model';

import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";


declare var require: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-save',
  templateUrl: './save.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./save.component.css']
})
export class SaveComponent implements OnInit {


  prod = new Liv() ;
  test = require('../../services/index');


  constructor(public router: Router, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  saveProduit() {
    console.log(this.test.ApiClientService.prototype.sendRequest)
    this.prod.id = null;


      this.test.ApiClientService.prototype.save(this.prod)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("this is" + data);
        alert("ID:" + this.prod.nom);
        this.router.navigate(['show-all']);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });


}}
```

**../../service/index.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {
  Livre
} from './models';

/**
* Created with angular4-swagger-client-generator.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ApiClientService {

  private domain = 'http://localhost:8084';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject('domain') domain: string ) {
    if (domain) {
      this.domain = domain;
    }
  }


  public save(body: Livre): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    let uri = `/Livre/add`;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let params = new HttpParams();
    return this.sendRequest<any>('post', uri, headers, params, JSON.stringify(body));
  }

  private sendRequest<T>(method: string, uri: string, headers: HttpHeaders, params: HttpParams, body: any): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
     if (method === 'post') {
      return this.http.post<T>(this.domain + uri, body, { headers: headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'), params: params, observe: 'response' });
    } else {
      console.error('Unsupported request: ' + method);
      return Observable.throw('Unsupported request: ' + method);
    }
  }
}
```

**saveComponent.html**

```
<div class="container spacer">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Nouveau Livre:</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nom:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="prod.nom"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">auteur:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="prod.auteur"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">prix:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="prod.prix"/>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveProduit()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApiClientService} from '../services/index'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SaveComponent } from './save/save.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { DeleteComponent } from './delete/delete.component';
import { UpdateComponent } from './update/update.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { ShowAllComponent } from './show-all/show-all.component';

const appRoutes:Routes=[
{path:'new-produit',component:SaveComponent},
{path:'delete-produit',component:DeleteComponent},
{path:'update-produit',component:UpdateComponent},
{path:'search-produit',component:SearchComponent},
{path:'show-all',component:ShowAllComponent},
{path:'',redirectTo:'/show-all', pathMatch:'full'}

]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SaveComponent,
    DeleteComponent,
    UpdateComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    ShowAllComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule , HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), HttpModule, FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiClientService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**error**

```
SaveComponent.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at Object.ApiClientService.sendRequest (index.ts:90)
    at Object.ApiClientService.save (index.ts:32)
    at SaveComponent.saveProduit (save.component.ts:35)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SaveComponent.html:19)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at eval (core.js:10629)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
```

I try to import service with function require but de http is not injected in de ts file

Comment: Why are you dooing `this.test.ApiClientService.prototype.save` instead of `this.ApiClientService.save` and injecting the service in the client?

Comment: the path of service is generic I have a lot of service generic , example : service Product is in (../user/product/index.ts) and service Categorie is (../user/categorie/index.ts) and I would to use require(../user/product/index)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to use the dependency injection. You should not use the prototype way you were using as it will not instantiate the class properly.

For the service to be available for dependency injection, you would need to add it to the list of `provides` of your module. You might want to read on dependency injection [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

**SaveComponent.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Liv} from '../../services/models/liv.model';
import {Livre} from '../../services/models/livre.model';
import {ApiClientService} from '../../services/index';

import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

// ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-save',
  templateUrl: './save.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./save.component.css']
})
export class SaveComponent implements OnInit {

   // ...

  constructor(
    public router: Router, 
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private apiClientService: ApiClientService
  ) {}

  // ...    

  saveProduit() {
    this.prod.id = null;
    this.apiClientService.save(this.prod);
    // ...
```

Comment: I have to have a service generic the import is not known for my keys , I get the import from other service ther for I use require and I cant inject in constructor because i dont have it yet

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. Also, it's kind of basic that if you call the function of a prototype in JS the `this` context will not be the same as on a constructed object. You would need to manualy inject `HttpClient` in your function but that would go against angular philosophy. Maybe you should explain why you need to do things this way so that someone could suggest an alternative.

Comment: I solved it by using this ` var tes = require('../../services/contact/index'); tes = AppModule.injector.get(tes.ApiClientService); tes.save(this.contact) .subscribe(data=>{ this.contact=data; this.mode=2; },err=>{ console.log(err); }) ` but now I have to declare `tes.ApiClientService` in the provider into the methode of Component  and not use declaration in AppModule

Comment: Your use case is still not clear. That being said, you should clarify your question with a specific usecase to get better answers.

Comment: okk , well , 
my case , is to use a generic service  , because  i have a lot of sevices n that are generated by a swagger client API
Example : the first service is located on : ../user/product/index  and other service is on ../user/categories/index  , the famous method is to use : import service from 'path' , for my case the path is generic , so i can't use import , i used require('my service') , and i can call my services , but the services can't call http.post , so we used : `var tes = require('../../services/contact/index'); tes = AppModule.injector.get(tes.ApiClientService);`

Comment: and the probleme now is `ERROR Error: No provider for ApiClientService!` , because we don't have to use "  providers: [ApiClientService ]," in appModule , we search a way to use provider dynamically in the component , such as bootstrap provider : [bootstrap provider](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/angular-2-an-introduction-of-bootstrap-and-providers-1c60ffbb7604) , but it doesn't work :(

Comment: How many services do you have to need to load/inject them dinamicaly? Maybe there is something wrong with the way the project is structured/thought of. Also, you should add the details you have added here to your question for others to see.